# Is query filtering by a keyword going to perform better than filtering by an integer?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have a `posts` index which holds all the data for all the posts made by every user on a forum, and I wanted to search through the posts made by one particular user, containing the word videogame.

​

The query would look something like this.

​

```
'query' : {
  'body' : {
    'should': {
      'match': {
        'posts.text': {
          'query': 'videogame',
          'fuzziness': 2,
        }
      }
    },
    'filter':{
      'term' : {
        'user_id': 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now my mapping has it set such that user_id is mapped as an integer. Would I be able to achieve a query performance gain by having the filter term be a keyword instead? Coming from a SQL background, I'm not totally certain what field types are 'indexed' in the same way that SQL is, and I haven't been able to find very good documentation regarding it.

Comment: Elastic/Lucene has some optimisations when indexing number data-types, to enhance query time range queries. If you don't need this, use a keyword :D

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main section when it come to search data.  1. How ES index document, and second how query works. 
1.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html      2.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

I hope it should help you.